# How to make Continue reading link in HTML

Tags: html

I am new to the web design game and stackoverflow. 
I have this page with TONS of content but I want to on show half of it to save room.

I want to create a link that when click on shows the rest of the text ON THAT SAME PAGE.

I want the user to stay on that same page. If they clicked continue reading it reveals (and maybe if they clicked it again, it goes back.

Can this be done in HTML?

Comment: @SableFoste Not necessarily. He could split the text page into several different pages and load them in an inline frame on the main page. Each "text" page would have the 'continue reading' links that would load the next (or previous) page.

Comment: @LuFaMa Also, it could be achieved with CSS transformations. It's trick, but doable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible with HMTL. You need JavaScript.

[This script](http://jedfoster.com/Readmore.js/) is very easy to use. It works with jQuery. Read the doc and it should work easy for you.

But if you want to know how this can be done with JavaScript, take a look to [this](http://www.cssnewbie.com/showhide-content-css-javascript/#.Ul09gFBSgXs) step by step tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done in HTML alone.

You could use a hover combination with CSS, so that when you hover over an item it changes to visible (and unhover it returns to invisible).

But for a click, you should look into Javascript, especially looking at jQuery.  `toggle` will accomplish what you are looking for.

Warning: there is quite a bit of a learning curve if you are just starting with HTML.